# Why SKI when SK is complete

Tags: logic, computability, combinatory-logic

Why people talk about SKI calculus when S and K combinators can be used to create any other combinator including I?

Comment: The SKI system is natural in the sense that it is exactly what you need to prove the abstraction elimination theorem.

Comment: $I$ is included for convenience.

Comment: @ZhenLin what do you mean by "exactly what you need to prove elimination abstraction"? You could prove the same with SK. If you need identity you could always use SKK instead of I.

Comment: If you look at the proof, you will see that S, K, and I correspond precisely to each of the structural induction steps. Try proving it on your own!

Comment: One might also speculate: SKI makes a nice acronym (a pronouncable abbreviation), while SK has to be pronounced “ess-kay”.

Comment: How did you deduce I from SK? I does describe the truth of identity , that everything is equal to its self and for that reason alone reasonably important

Comment: @Willemien I has same effect as SKK

Answer (score 2):

As was mentioned in comments, **S**, **K** and **I** correspond exactly to what is needed to prove abstraction elimination, in the nice tidy sense that each case syntactical case in the induction step has exactly one combinator that handles that case alone.

Apart from that, however, one can also argue that **I** is more fundamental than the two other operators. It would be a very strange logic that didn't prove $A\to A$, but logics that reject **S** or **K** do exist. *Linear logic*, for example, rejects both; **S** because it corresponds to duplication of resources and **K** because it throws resources away.

So when describing a set of combinators, it is easier and more convenient to say, "yes of course we have **I**" than to let the reader spend energy on figuring out how **I** can be made from other available combinators.

Comment: Shouldn't this logic be kept minimal when I is trivial to be found using S and K? In fact it so easy that it might be presented as one of first exercises in most basic courses.

Comment: "Should" is subjective. There's no rule saying that anyone has a duty to stick to considering minimal systems only.